# Async REST-Api calls without RabbitMq possible?

Tags: rest-api, magento2.3.2

I tried to use the "Bulk endpoints" from this example:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/bulk-endpoints.html

The answer from Test-Shop was a 500 Error. A normal single Rest-Api call works.

```
Message: Unknown connection name amqp {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Report ID: webapi-5d9c757ec15b6; 
Message: Unknown connection name amqp at /vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:208, LogicException(code: 0): 
Unknown connection name amqp at /vendor/magento/framework-message-queue/ConnectionTypeResolver.php:43)"}
```

At the moment I don't want to setup a RabbitMQ Server. So how do I configure Magento to use normal cronjob to serve Rest-API-Calls like the one from the Bulk Example?

Comment: Were you able to progress further with this without RabbitMQ?

Comment: No, we will probably use RabbitMQ